# Match a regular expression against any non-character or number

Tags: php, pattern-matching

Ok, here again.
I'll promise to study deeply the regular expression soon :P

Language: PhP

Problem:
Match if some badword exist inside a string and do something.
The word must be not included inside a "greater word". I mean if i'll search for "**rob**" (sorry Rob, i'm not thinking you're a badword), the word "p**rob**lem have to pass without check.

I'd googled around but found nothing good for me. So, I thought something like this:

If i match the word with after and before any character of the following:

- .

  ,

  ;

  :

  !

  ?

  (

  )

  +

  -

  [whitespace]

I can simulate a check against single word inside a string.

Finally the Questions:

1. There's a better way to do it?

   If not, which will be the correct regexp to consider *[all_that_char]***word***[all_that_char]*?

Thanks in advance to anyone would help!
Maybe this is a very stupid question but today is one of *that* day when move our neurons causes an incredible headache :|

Comment: It's PHP, not PhP. The lack of a taller 'H' is going to inspire rage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up `\b` (word boundary):

> Matches at the position between a word
>   character (anything matched by \w) and
>   a non-word character (anything matched
>   by [^\w] or \W) as well as at the
>   start and/or end of the string if the
>   first and/or last characters in the
>   string are word characters.

(http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

So: `\brob\b` matches `rob`, but not `problem`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\b`, see [Whole word bounderies](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).